# mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file while taking inputs

Tags: php, post, mpdf

i created test1.php view this file contain inputs value in form on submit button redirecting to checkpdf.php , for creating pdf invoice file .but getting this error. how can solve it. in check pdf file getting all proper values without genrating pdf for testing.
following in code is in checkpdf.php
[please check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ3Ue.jpg) 
this is my test1.php view page

```html
<?php
include 'config.php';

$query= "select * from qaote_dets";

if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$query))
  {
  // Fetch one and one row

  // Free result set
 
?>
<html>
    <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="col-md-12"> 
        <h1>Test </h1>
        </div>
       <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top: 32px;"> 
           <div class="col-md-8" style="float:left;">
               
               <form action='checkpdf.php' method='POST' id='quatepdf'> 
              <table border="1">
                  <tr>
                      <th>#sr. no</th>
                      <th>item no.</th>
                      <th>item description</th>
                      <th>quantity</th>
                      <th>price/unit</th>
                  </tr>    
                  <?php           
                  $i = 1;
                  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                 {
                      ?>
                 <tr id="row<?php echo $i ?>">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="check1" id="checkdet<?php echo $i;?>" name="checkboxtest[]" value="<?php  echo $row[1]; ?>">  
                     </td> 
                     <td>         
                         <input type="text" class="form-control text1" id="text1" value="<?php  echo $row[1]; ?> " name='item_name[]'><br>
                      </td>
                     <td>
                         <textarea class="form-control item desc"  value="" name='item_desc[]'><?php  echo $row[2];?></textarea>  
                     </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control quantity<?php  echo $i;?>" value="1" name='qty[]'> 
                     </td>
                     <td>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control amnt<?php  echo $i;?> " readonly="" name='amnt[]' value="<?php  echo $row[3];?>" > 
                    <input type="hidden" class="service<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php  echo $row[4];?>" name='service[]'> 
                      </td>
                  </tr>  
                <?php     $i++;    }  mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);?>  
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                      <th  colspan="3">Total</th>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="text"  readonly="" id="totamnt" value="" name="tolval">
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                      <th  colspan="3">GSt(18%)</th>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="text"  readonly="" id="gst" value="" name="gstamt">
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td>
                      <th  colspan="3">Final Amount</th>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="text"  readonly="" id="finamt" value="" name="finalamt">
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
             
               <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:10px;">
                   <div class="col-md-4" style="float: left;">
                       <input type="button" value="Calculate" class="btn-success" id="Calculate"> 
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4" style="float: left;">
                       <input type="submit" value="Genrate Pdf" class="btn-success" name="pdfbtn"> 
                   </div>
               <div class="col-md-4"></div>
               </div>   
                    </form>
       </div>
        
        
       <div class="col-md-4" style="float:left;">
           <table border = "1">
               <tr>
                   <th>add product</th>
                   <th>#Sr no.</th>
                   <th>Item code</th>
                   <th>amount</th>
                   <th>installation charges</th>
               </tr>
                 <?php       
                  $i =1;
                  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                 {
                     
                      ?>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       <input type="checkbox" class="" name="" id="check<?php echo $i?>">
                   </td>
                   <td>
                     <span class=""> <?php  echo $i;?></span> 
                   </td>
                   <td>
                     <span class=""><?php  echo $row[1];?> </span> 
                   </td>
                   <td>
                     <span class=""><?php  echo $row[3];?> </span> 
                   </td>
                   <td>
                     <span class=""><?php  echo $row[4];?></span> 
                   </td>
               </tr>
                 <?php $i++; } ?>
           </table>
           
       
         </div>
     </div>   
    </body>
</html>

<?php

 mysqli_free_result($result);
}
?>
```

this is my redirected checkpdf.php page

```html
<?php
include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");
$logoFile = 'ssi.jpg';
$logoXPos = 10;
$logoYPos = 10;
$logoWidth = '40px';

        /*   valus checked  */
$item_code = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_desc = $_POST['item_desc'];
$quantity = $_POST['qty'];
$price = $_POST['amnt'];
$service = $_POST['service'];
$totamt =  $_POST['tolval'];
$gst =  $_POST['gstamt'];
$final =  $_POST['finalamt'];
/*   close */


$pdf = new mPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
//$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Image( $logoFile, $logoXPos, $logoYPos, $logoWidth );
$pdf->WriteFixedPosHTML("<span> abc infotech<span>",550, 20, 50, 90, 'auto');
$pdf->WriteFixedPosHTML("<span> A-103, trimak co-op  soc<span>",550, 25, 50, 90, 'auto');
$pdf->WriteFixedPosHTML("<span> vani ali, gandhi chowk<span>",550, 30, 50, 90, 'auto');
$pdf->WriteFixedPosHTML("<span> Badlapur(e) 421503<span>",550, 35, 50, 90, 'auto');
$pdf->WriteFixedPosHTML("<hr>",00, 44, 550, 55, 'auto');
$pdf->WriteFixedPosHTML("<div style='background-color:orange;'><span style='color:#000'>abc infotrch<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span stye='color:#000';>abcinfo@gmail.com</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style='color:#000;'>contact : 9998898989</span></div>",50, 755, 1000, 5, 'auto');


// if(isset($_POST['pdfbtn'])){
if(!empty($_POST['checkboxtest'])) {

$htmlTable='<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>S. No.</th>
<th>Item code</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>quantity</td>
<th>amount</th>
<th>service</th>
</tr>';
    $i=1;
      foreach($_POST['checkboxtest'] as $check) {
          
          $htmlTable.='<tr>';
           $htmlTable.='<td>'.$i;
            
             $htmlTable.='</td>';
             $htmlTable.='<td>'.$item_code[$i];
                  
          $htmlTable.='</td>';
           $htmlTable.='<td>'. $item_desc[$i];
                   
            $htmlTable.='</td>';  
             $htmlTable.='<td>'.$quantity[$i];
                  
             $htmlTable.='</td>';  
              $htmlTable.='<td>'.$price[$i];;
                  
              $htmlTable.='</td>';
              $htmlTable.='<td>'.$service[$i];     
                
             $htmlTable.='</td>';    
          
            $i++;
      }
  $htmlTable.='</tr>' ;
           $htmlTable.='<tr> <td colspan=3> Total Amount   </td>'  ; 
             $htmlTable.='</tr> <td >'.$totamt.'</td></tr>'  ; 
              $htmlTable.='<tr> <td colspan=3>Gst(18%) </td>'  ; 
             $htmlTable.='</tr> <td >'.$gst.'</td></tr>'  ; 
              $htmlTable.='<tr> <td colspan=3> Final Amount   </td>'  ; 
             $htmlTable.='</tr> <td >'.$final.'</td></tr>'  ; 
            
$htmlTable.='</table>';
}
// }

$pdf->WriteHTML($htmlTable);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: You have a lot of warnings, which is already echoed. So u cant get ur mpdf output. Try to fix those warnings. Everything willbe fine.

Comment: @shan its working on unix machine buts having issue with widows machine is there any setting?

Comment: any one can solve this issue

Comment: please turnoff error reporting & see if it works. But its better to fix those warnings..

Comment: It seems you are trying to use mPDF 6.0 on PHP 7.1 which is not supported. For PHP 7.1 support, upgrade to mPDF 7.0.1, the notices should then be resolved.

Comment: yes, issue has been solved by using jst error_reporting(0)
i didn't use this becuase i created this on linux and theres working fine, same i was trying on windows its giving waring, so thought issue of firewall or somthing else, but its fine now